# Sum paired files over a list of files

Tags: r

I have multiple files where two and two files belong together and should be summed based on values in column 2 to create one file. All files have the same rows. The files that should be summed have similar ID before the `L*` part of the string. 
I would like to make a loop that identifies the paired files and sums in based on column 2.

I have created a function that reads the files, but not sure how to proceed:

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv)

library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(file_list, function(x) 
  fread(x, select=c("V1", "V2"))[, 
                                 list(ID=paste(V1), freq=V2)])
```

Below is shown two of the pairs:

Pair one:

01_001_F08_S80_**L009**

```
16S_rRNA_copy_A-1   75
16S_rRNA_copy_B-1   86
16S_rRNA_copy_C-1   102
```

01_001_F08_S80_**L002**

```
16S_rRNA_copy_A-1   98
16S_rRNA_copy_B-1   96
16S_rRNA_copy_C-1   101
```

Pair two:

01_001_F09_S81_**L006**

```
16S_rRNA_copy_A-1   242
16S_rRNA_copy_B-1   244
16S_rRNA_copy_C-1   302
```

01_001_F09_S81_**L003**

```
16S_rRNA_copy_A-1   252
16S_rRNA_copy_B-1   253
16S_rRNA_copy_C-1   322
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the data by the substring of the `names` of the 'lst' (created with `sub`), loop through the `list`, `rbind` the nested `list` elements, grouped by 'ID', get the `sum`

```
lapply(split(lst, sub("\\d+$", "", names(lst))), 
               function(x) rbindlist(x)[, .(freq = sum(freq)), ID])
#$`01_001_F08_S80_L`
#                  ID freq
#1: 16S_rRNA_copy_A-1  173
#2: 16S_rRNA_copy_B-1  182
#3: 16S_rRNA_copy_C-1  203

#$`01_001_F09_S81_L`
#                  ID freq
#1: 16S_rRNA_copy_A-1  494
#2: 16S_rRNA_copy_B-1  497
#3: 16S_rRNA_copy_C-1  624
```